# Multiple PHP versions released on same day

Tags: php

I have just noticed the banner across the top of php.net, stating that `PHP 7.0.20` has been released. I thought it a bit strange since I'm using `PHP 7.1.5`. [Following the link](http://php.net/archive/2017.php#id2017-05-11-2) has left me very confused.

- PHP 7.0.20: Released 08 Jun 2017
- PHP 7.1.5: Released 11 May 2017
- PHP 7.0.19: Released 11 May 2017

Is there any significance to `7.1.5` version number and it being released on the same day as `7.0.19` and being released before the lesser version of `7.0.20`?

I can understand them skipping the whole `6.x.x`, but the current `7.x.x` version seem to be just mishmashed.

Comment: There's a 7.x branch and a 7.1.x branch. They are both maintained.

Comment: See [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). 7.1.* is the latest overall version but 5.6.* and 7.0.* are still maintained for bug updates, so 7.0.20 is a bugfix release for 7.0.* that just happened to come out after 7.1.5 was released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently three versions of PHP under [development and support](http://php.net/supported-versions.php): 5.6 (security fixes only), 7.0 and 7.1 (active development and support).

They go in parallel and many times patch versions (when the 3<sup>rd</sup> component of the version changes) are released for all three of them on the same day. Such releases fix bugs or security issues and it is normal to be fixed on all currently supported versions.

Answer (score 2):

In the development of PHP, the middle number is a significant version change where new features or breaking changes can occur. Due to this, the previous version is still maintained with bug fixes and security updates.

Consider you had a production server running PHP 7.0.19. When there is a bug fix or security release (7.0.20), you may only want those updates, you don't necessarily want a major version update up to 7.1 on your production server that could cause errors due to breaking changes or removed features.

Comment: If the minor version number signifies breaking changes, what does major version signify? These version numbers don't correspond to what I'm used to with composer/symfony packages.

Comment: In practice, large breaking changes and removed features are usually reserved for the major version, for example `mysql_*` removed if you update from PHP5 to 7. The minor version changes are usually small new features but often there are some incompatibilities between the previous minor verson that could be breaking changes.